# Return string rather than database entry in CSV export using csv_from_result

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, csv

I am using codeigniter to produce a CSV from a database entry. The following code works

```
$this->load->dbutil();
$csv = $this->dbutil->csv_from_result($stories);
echo $csv;

$name = 'data.csv';

// Build the headers to push out the file properly.
header('Pragma: public');     // required
header('Expires: 0');         // no cache
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Cache-Control: private',false);
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($name).'"');  // Add the file name
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Connection: close');
exit();

force_download($name, $csv);
fclose($fp);
```

However, I have two questions.

1) Why does my code rely on echoing $CSV? It returns a blank cvs if I comment out this line.

2) How do I take the $CSV variable and edit it. At the moment my database stores some information as integers that the controllers turn to strings in the normal running of the site i.e. I might store the priority in the database as 0,1,2 but in the view I show Urgent,high,low. I would like to show these strings in the exported CSV rather than the database entry. I am a bit confused as to how I do this. I was thinking of a loop with a switch statement but I dont really know how to interact with the $CSV variable - Or should I be doing this in the model where the data is still in an object rather than csv_from_result()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) `$csv` contains all the information, it is all the content that makes up your file. That's why if you don't echo it out you just get a blank CSV file.

2) You don't want to edit `$csv`, that variable contains everything ready to go. You want to edit `$stories`, which from the looks of what you have pasted above contains everything from your database that then gets converted into CSV by `$this->dbutil->csv_from_result`. Look through your code and find where `$stories` is loaded, then modify that.

Comment: 1. I understand that $CSV contains all the info, just wondering why I need to echo this as isn't that just to print it to the browser. Do I need to do that because I am streaming to the browser or something? 2. $stories is simply the resulting object from the database query but you are right that this is the part I should be looking at. Not sure how I missed that.

Comment: @Drdavidpier Effectively what you are doing is creating a new page, just with a bunch of different headers which tell the browser to process it as a CSV file and to download it from the server. But without echoing any content to the page, there's nothing for the browser to download.